# Password file migration

Tags: php, encryption, passwords

I have an application written in php Ver. 3.
The application has a users file with usernames and passwords. The passwords are encrypted using the PASSWORD() function.

We need to transfer this file and utilize it under a system using php 5.
We tried to use the password() function again to check the validity of a password entered by the user, but the encrypted results don't match.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What `password()` function are you talking about?

Comment: show us the contents of `password()` method

Comment: Are you referring to the *MySQL* function `PASSWORD`?

Comment: Let's all keep guessing.

Answer (score 3):

PHP has never had a `PASSWORD()` function. If you're talking about the MySQL function, the hashing algorithm was change in MySQL 4.1 (a long time ago). You can use `OLD_PASSWORD()` to generate password hashes using the old method, or you can set the `old_passwords` system variable to have MySQL default to it.

In any case you should make arrangements to migrate from the old system to the new one. Since you can't know what the old password was, you'll probably need to code a mechanism to force users to change their passwords and track which version they're using.

The MySQL reference on this is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-hashing.html)